# Is there any delegate which fires while app is killed from background only?

Tags: ios

Is there any delegate which fires while app is killed from background in iPhone X?

Comment: Why iPhone X? Why would that be different from any other iPhone?

Comment: You should probably clarify what you mean with "killed _from_ background" or did you mean while the app is in the background?

Comment: Yes in iPhone X if app is open , then goes to background and then terminate, so application will terminate not getting called

Answer (score 1):

No. Your app is suspended. It can't get any events because it isn't running. If the app is running in the background, you might get `applicationWillTerminate:` if the *user* terminates the app, but I wouldn't count on it. Basically you should assume when the app goes into the background that it might be terminated.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is please refer to Pushkit framework, I have done that same task using this library, Here][1](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/) is the link all you need to set up, if you want to try in kill mode, you need to do this on Xcode => [image: here =>] go to edit scheme in your Xcode.

After setting all this you will be able to do all you need